# Is it possible to include all the openzeppelin library files on Remix?

Tags: contract-development, remix, openzeppelin

I am trying out Remix as an IDE. However, I'm using the excellent open-zeppelin library for development. Is there any way to include all the files from open-zeppelin in the build path for Remix without pasting them all in there?

I have tried importing a local directory, but since my normal build tool is Truffle, the Remix compiler doesn't pick up the `node_modules` directory. I tried copying the open-zeppelin directory into the `contracts` directory, but still my imports won't work. They work if I prefix my paths "./", but I'd rather not do that, since I would have to do it in every single open-zeppelin file.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest is to use remixd to share your build directory with remix. Here are indication how to configure it [Accessing a shared folder in Remix IDE using Remixd](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_remixd_filesystem.html).

Another option is to use the remix feature that allows importing directly from github, so you do not need the openzeppelin files.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract BasicToken is Ownable {
    function () public payable {
    }

    function withdraw(uint amount) public {
        if (amount <= this.balance) {
            msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a shared folder with remixd. The point is, I don't want to rewrite all my import statements in order to be able to work in Remix. My code (and the zeppelin code) already contains import statements of the type `import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";`. I'd like the import statements to stay that way.

Comment: URL is dead unfortunately

Comment: @Emobe Remix has changed a lot from two years ago. The new URL seems to be https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remixd.html.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Patricio Palladino's [`truffle-flattener`](https://github.com/alcuadrado/truffle-flattener)?

> Truffle Flattener concats solidity files developed under Truffle with
>   all of their dependencies.
>
> This tool helps you to verify contracts developed with Truffle on
>   Etherscan, or debugging them on Remix, by merging your files and their
>   dependencies in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible just use:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract SimpleContract is Ownable {

}
```

The package `zeppelin-solidity` mentioned above is deprecated

Comment: Problem is the openzeppelin-solidity contracts import other ones and they don't use the github link. This is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can import with github.

```
https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import.html
```

ie:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0-solc-0.7/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {

    constructor () ERC20("Token", "TKN") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
    }
}
```